# behavior of coord_trans(x="log10") in combination with scale_x_log10 when applied with stat_density

Tags: r, ggplot2

The `stat_density` help page gives these examples:

```
(m <- ggplot(movies, aes(x=votes)) + geom_density(trim = TRUE))
m + scale_x_log10()
m + scale_x_log10() + coord_trans(x="log10")
```

Why does the last line give a different result than the 2nd? Since `scale_x_log10` transforms the `x` variable before density calculation and *also* plots it on a log10 scale, the last coordinate transformation seems redundant and yet the output graphic does not look the same.

Comment: you're adding another layer and another transformation. why do you expect adding `coord_trans(x="log10")` will not change anything

Comment: In `?coord_trans`, it says "`coord_trans is different to scale transformations in that it occurs after statistical transformation and will affect the visual appearance of geoms`". Comparing the two plots in your example, it looks like using `coord_trans(x="log10")` after `scale_x_log10()` is distorting the density curve to reflect its (additional) rescaling of the x axis.

Comment: @nrussell, yes I agree - but why does `coord_trans(x="log10")` need to rescale the x axis when it is already in log10 scale after the `scale_x_log10` operation?

Comment: @rawr: I wouldn't expect it to do anything since it is already in log10 scale after the `scale_x_log10` transformation.

Comment: @crippledlambda It's hard to say why it is this way without being able to see the source code for these functions; the best I can do is speculate based on excerpts from the documentation. In the `Examples` section of the help file for `coord_trans`, it says "`With a combination of scale and coordinate transformation, it's
possible to do back-transformations`" - so possibly this is the main reason for being able combine scale transformations with coordinate transformations. Maybe @hadley can answer this question for you.